# Routing between Modules in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing, ng-modules

I'm building simple angular application. There are two modules as **student** and **teacher**.
Here is how my project organized.

[image: Project structure]

First when the user enters the application, I let them choose whether they are a teacher or student.

Depending on that choice, the user will be redirected to the corresponding module.

Here is my `app.routing.ts` file.

```js
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {StudentModule} from './student/student.module';
import {TeacherModule} from './teacher/teacher.module';
import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
    
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'student',
        loadChildren: () => StudentModule
    },
    {
        path: 'teacher',
        loadChildren: () => TeacherModule
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

My problem is when I navigate into a module, I want to also navigate between components in the other module. Should I add another `<router-outlet>` into each module, or can I do that with the `<router-outlet>` in `AppModule`.

If I should add another `<router-outlet>`, how should I write my router class for those modules.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Lazy loading way Angular v8, v9 and Up**

https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

```
// In app module route
{
 path: 'your-path',
 loadChildren: () => import('./path-to/your.module').then(m => m.YourModule)
}

// in your module
const yourRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '',  component: YourComponent }
];

export const yourRouting = RouterModule.forChild(yourRoutes);

@NgModule({
  imports: [
   yourRouting
  ],
  declarations: [
    YourComponent
  ]
})
export class YourModule{
}
```

**Lazy loading way Angular v7, v6 and down**

```
// In app module route
{
 path: 'your-path',
 loadChildren: 'app/your.module#YourModule'
}

// in your module
const yourRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '',  component: YourComponent }
];

export const yourRouting = RouterModule.forChild(yourRoutes);

@NgModule({
  imports: [
   yourRouting
  ],
  declarations: [
    YourComponent
  ]
})
export class YourModule{
}
```

**Not lazy loading way**

Just import the `YourModule` in the main module and it will work if the routes are not lazily loaded.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    YourModule,
    routing
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    appRoutingProviders
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Take some time to read rout documentation https://angular.io/guide/router

Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39284277/6786941

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to define routing for individual modules and in the module component file you need to provide

Below should be the file structure

```
- Teacher 
   -teacher.component.html  --> here you should put <router-outlet>
   -techer-routing.module.ts --> here you need to define routes for teacher module
   -teacher.module.ts --> import techer-routing.module here
   -Logincomponent
        -login.component.html
        -login.component.ts
   -Homecomponent
        -home.component.html
        -home.component.ts
```

Same as another module for students.

Next step is to specify teacher module internal routes.
below are the probable content of

teacher-routing.module.ts

Below are the sample routes for teacher module

```
 const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: TeacherComponent, children: [
    {path: '', component: TeacherComponent,data: {title: "Teachers"}},
    {path: 'Home',  component:HomeComponent, data: {title: "Home"}},
    {path: 'Register',  component:RegisterComponent, data: {title: 
      "Register"}},
     ]
   }
 ]

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})

export class TeacherRoutingModule{}
```

Comment: Yes, you need to add that.